# Rabbinical definition of "a clean and easy profession"

Tags: melacha-creative-work

> רַבִּי מֵאִיר אוֹמֵר: לְעוֹלָם יְלַמֵּד אָדָם אֶת בְּנוֹ אֻמָּנוּת נְקִיָּה וְקַלָּה,
>
> Rabbi Meir says: one should always teach his son
> **a clean and easy profession.** (Mishna [Kiddushin 4,14](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Kiddushin.4.14?vhe=Torat_Emet_357&lang=bi)).

The Gemmorah elaborates ([82,b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Kiddushin.82b.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)):

> מאי היא אמר רב יהודה - מחטא דתלמיותא
> Needlework for embroidery is a clean and easy trade.

I don't recall a Rabbi that was an embroidered, or maybe there's a hidden meaning into it.

What does it mean: "a clean and easy profession"? What is "clean" and what is "easy"?

Comment: “Clean from theft and not big risk factor” tosfat yomtov

Comment: @AlBerko I understood that Gemara to be providing an example, not to say that this is the only job one should take.

Answer (score 2):

**My own explanation:**

What does it mean: "a clean and easy profession"?

***What is "clean"?***

"Clean" refers to a type of profession that is performed in a clean atmosphere, one where Torah thoughts may be had. For example, being a plumber is not such a "clean" profession, since it involves a lot of time working in bathrooms, and/or dealing with foul smelling sewage.

***What is "easy"?***

"Easy" refers to work that is repetitive, and does not require much brain power or concentration. A computer programmer may work in a "clean" environment, but his work isn't "easy", in the sense that it requires a lot of concentration.

Using these definitions, needlework for embroidery is an example of a clean and easy trade.

It has both qualities. It is "clean". It can be practiced in a relatively clean environment. It is also "easy". Once a person has mastered the skill of stitching, the work itself does not require much concentration, and can be performed by rote.

***Why is this type of profession desirable?***

See [Nefesh Hachaim (Shaar 1, 8)](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A0%D7%A4%D7%A9_%D7%94%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D/%D7%A9%D7%A2%D7%A8_%D7%90/%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A7_%D7%97) who posits, that even according to R. Yishmael who holds that authority is given to a person to leave the Torah for a short while, and to engage in a livelihood, nevertheless at the very same time that you are engaged in making a bare living, your thoughts should be occupied with Torah.

Therefore, someone trying to fulfill the directive of the Nefesh Hachaim, would look to find "a clean and easy profession", one that would allow him to earn a living, and simultaneously allow him to think Torah thoughts while performing his work.

Comment: Thank you, if this advice was given by a layman I'd believe what you explained, but I'd expect the Mishnah to discuss something more "Heaven or Mitzvah related". Interestingly we see that lots of Rabbis chose "unclean" and not an easy profession, while nobody did embroidery. Isn't it so?

Comment: This is "Heaven or Mitzvah related". Advice in choosing a vocation that will allow you to maximize your learning, even though you need to work.

Answer (score 2):

See the Ikkar Tosfos:

> נקיה כו'. בגמרא מחטא דתלמיותא. כלומר תופר בגדים קרועים. והיינו תלמיותא
>   שהתפירות עשויות שורות שורות כתלמים של מחרישה. רש''י. והערוך מסיים נקיה
>   מגזל וקלה דאין בה חסרון כיס:

Sounds like they understood it to be simple tailoring. And quoting the Aruch explains "Clean" means free from corruption. And "easy" means it doesn't require a large investment of resources

In terms of which Rabbis were Tailors, there were many great Sages that were חייטים.

Comment: Tailoring is a good idea (I like it better than embroidery!). The rest, however, doesn't sound as Halachic advice. But maybe it isn't.